# Silence output of maven-dependency-plugin with 'silent' parameter

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I just updated the version of the maven-dependency-plugin and now I get several new message like
`Copying fileXY.jar` or `artifactXY.jar already exists in destination` and so forth...

I want to silence those message however I do not want to silence warnings or errors. The [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#silent) is not helpful in that matter, since it only says (who would have guessed that)

`If the plugin should be silent.`

So my question is: What exactly is silenced?

Comment: First question: Why do you need maven-dependency-plugin?

Comment: Counter question: What are the major advantages of using the maven-dependency-plugin?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if you want to eliminate the `Copying…` output, you cannot unless you turn off Maven logging entirely.  [The `maven-dependency-plugin` source code shows why.](https://github.com/apache/maven-dependency-plugin/blob/7e6379db978a7937c8430b8f8d58cdfcddbdfc7d/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/dependency/AbstractDependencyMojo.java#L180-L182)

Comment: Ok I can maybe live with the "copying" message but the "already exists in destination" message goes away using silent? What about warnings?